# something 'does' get picked up. what is 'does' for

Tags: understanding

I have heard this sentence in a game. **The tank does get picked up**.

I know **do/does** is used in **the simple present form** in a question or a negative sentence.

- do I play?
- I don't play.

However, I don't understand why it has been used in this sentence.

it is equal to **The tank gets picked up** or **The tank is picked up**. Is it?

Answer (score 3):

In this context, saying, "The tank does get picked up," is generally equivalent to "the tank gets picked up" or "the tank is picked up" but gives a distinct emphasis on confirming that yes, the tank is picked up.

As far as your example, you can certainly answer, "do you play..." by answering, "I do play..." and the "do" emphasizes that the answer is "yes."  Use of the "to do" verb acts sort of like an auxiliary verb in that sense.  If you lived 300-400 years ago, that question would be more likely to be asked as, "play you...?" (or technically "play ye" for plural, because "you" was plural back then, or "playest thou" for singular) without the use of the auxiliary verb, and instead of how we would ask "are you going..." with the auxiliary verb "to be" they would ask "go you..."

Comment: _You_ and _ye_ were both plural (though 300–400 years ago is exactly when that started really falling apart); the difference was one of case, not number. _Ye_ was subject case, _you_ was oblique case. The singular equivalents were _thou_ and _thee_, respectively. So if asking a single person, it would have been, “Playest thou…?” back then; if asking several people, it would be, “Play ye…?”.

Comment: Oh, you're right!  Mea culpa!  I'll correct my original post.